# Classification with 500 Categories

Tags: classification, categorical-data, references, multi-class, many-categories

Currently I am working on several projects with classification algorithms. The number of categories is very high (between 100 and 4 000, but let us assume it is 500).

Which algorithms are suitable for such problems?

---

If you need an example for explaining your answer you can assume these values:

1. 30 independent variables
2. 500 Categories
3. 200 000 observations
4. Each category has at least 25 observations
5. No missing data
6. Only positive data and no extreme outliers

---

I am looking for an idea at how to start and I would also appreciate any simple papers which would be good introductory readings for this project.

Comment: Can you say something about the categories? For instance, is there some hierarchical structure on the categories?

Comment: I am rather looking for a general introduction to classification with ~500 categories. Let us assume that there is no hierarchical structure and more or less balanced classes.

Comment: Well, no experience with such problems ... I would maybe start with some descriptive analysis, maybe some form of multidimensional scaling, or clustering of the categories ... Maybe try some simple models like random forrest or multinomial logistic regression ...

Comment: Yeah I stick to RF because they are more robust to multicollinearity and overfitting than multinomial logistic regression. In general I do not find any papers/ material about this topic. :-(

Comment: Try google scholar ... that means there is a good opportunity to write papers about such problems.

Comment: Either there is a good opportunity to write papers about such problems or such problems are extremely complicated or I am extremely bad at searching